# functor between the category of Finite sets which is not monoidal

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

If I consider the category of finite sets with the monoidal product defined by the cartesian product are there endofunctors which are not monoidal functors? if so I was wondering if there is a classification of endofunctors of this category? i.e. what do all of them look like?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128898/does-every-functor-from-set-to-set-preserve-products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many examples, for one any constant functor to a set with more than 1 element. Any example you give is inherently not representable because $C(c,-)$ respects products. However, being monoidal here is not enough to guarantee being representable. One such example is given by the constant functor to the empty set.